# How can I rename all columns of a data frame based on another data frame in R?

Tags: r

I am very new to R.  I am trying to rename the columns of a data frame based on another dataframe.

Essentially My data looks like

DataFrame1

```
A    B    C   D
1    2    3   4
```

I have another table that looks like this'
DataFrame2

```
Col1    Col2
A       E
B       Q
C       R
D       Z
```

I want to rename the columns of my first data frame based on this table so that it will come out:

```
E    Q    R    Z
1    2    3    4
```

I was trying a loop using the plyr library.  This is the command I tried:

```
library(plyr)
for (i in names(DataFrame1[,3:336])) #renaming columns 3 to 336
    { 
        rename(DataFrame1,
         replace = c(i = DataFrame2[DataFrame2$Col1 == i, 2])) 
    }
```

My thinking was for each column in DataFrame1, rename the column with the lookup of the column in DataFrame2.

This produces N Rows of the error "The following `from` values were not present in `x`: i", where n is the number of rows present in DataFrame1

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: For future reference it's preferred for you to share your example data in a reproducible way, such writing the code to create it or using `dput`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
A    B    C   D
1    2    3   4

DataFrame1 <- read.table(con <- file("clipboard"), header=T)

Col1    Col2
A       E
B       Q
C       R
D       Z

DataFrame2 <- read.table(con <- file("clipboard"), header=T)

colnames(DataFrame1) <- DataFrame2$Col2
```

If the column names didn't go in order like they do in the example you'd have to use `match`:

```
DataFrame2$Col2[match(names(DataFrame1),DataFrame2$Col1)]
```

Comment: Might be safer to `match` them to each other - `dat2$Col2[match(names(dat1),dat2$Col1)]`

Comment: Wow! So easy >_<.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks, if `df1`'s column names not in `df2$Col1`, then I hope to keep it as original, how could I modify your code at this case?

Comment: @ahbon I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Can you make a new question with an example then put the link to it as a comment so that I can find it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can rename the columns in base R

```
dt1 <- data.frame(A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4)

dt2 <- data.frame(Col1=c("A","B","C","D"),Col2=c("E","Q","R","Z"))

names(dt1) <- dt2$Col2

print(dt1)

E Q R Z
1 2 3 4
```

Replace and ifelse function may also rename the column names if data frames has same length

```
names(dt1) <- replace(names(dt1),!is.na(names(dt1)),dt2$Col2)
names(dt1) <- ifelse(!is.na(names(dt1)),dt2$Col2,NA)

print(dt1)

E Q R Z
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `setnames` from "data.table" for this:

```
library(data.table)
# Might not work if your columns are factors, not characters
# setnames(dt1, dt2$Col1, dt2$Col2)[]

# Convert to character to use
setnames(dt1, as.character(dt2$Col1), as.character(dt2$Col2))[]
#   E Q R Z
# 1 1 2 3 4
```

If the `data.frame` containing the old and new names have more names than need to be replaced, you can add `skip_absent=TRUE` to `setnames`.