# Rename columns of a dataframe based on another dataframe except columns not in that dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Given two dataframes `df1` and `df2` as follows:

**df1:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = 1L, B = 2L, C = 3L, D = 4L, G = 5L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Out:

```
  A B C D G
1 1 2 3 4 5
```

**df2:**

```
df2 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "X"), Col2 = c("E", 
"Q", "R", "Z", "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Out:

```
  Col1 Col2
1    A    E
2    B    Q
3    C    R
4    D    Z
5    X    Y
```

I need to rename columns of `df1` using `df2`, except column `G` since it not in `df2`'s `Col1`.

I use `df2$Col2[match(names(df1), df2$Col1)]` based on the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625024/how-can-i-rename-all-columns-of-a-data-frame-based-on-another-data-frame-in-r/38625108?noredirect=1#comment123431659_38625108), but it returns `"E" "Q" "R" "Z" NA`, as you see column `G` become `NA`. I hope it keep the original name.

The expected result:

```
  E Q R Z G
1 1 2 3 4 5
```

How could I deal with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the update you made for `df2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using the `rename_with` function from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  filter(Col1 %in% names(df1))

df4 <- df1 %>%
  rename_with(.cols = df3$Col1, .fn = function(x) df3$Col2[df3$Col1 %in% x])

df4
#   E Q R Z G
# 1 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: It works with new code, last one generates `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `X` doesn't exist`.

Comment: @ahbon My original code works for your original example. Since you changed `df2`, we need to filter the `df2` to make sure all `Col1` content exist in the column name of `df1`.

Answer (score 2):

By using `na.omit`(it's little bit messy..)

```
colnames(df1)[na.omit(match(names(df1), df2$Col1))] <- df2$Col2[na.omit(match(names(df1), df2$Col1))]
df1

  E Q R Z G
1 1 2 3 4 5
```

I have success to reproduce your error with

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  Col1 = c("H","I","K","A","B","C","D"),
  Col2 = c("a1","a2","a3","E","Q","R","Z")
)
```

The problem is location of `df2$Col1` and `names(df1)` in match.

```
na.omit(match(names(df1), df2$Col1))
```

gives `[1] 4 5 6 7`, which index does not exist in `df1` that has length 5.

For `df1`, we should change order of terms in `match`, `na.omit(match(df2$Col1,names(df1)))` gives `[1] 1 2 3 4`

```
colnames(df1)[na.omit(match(df2$Col1, names(df1)))] <- df2$Col2[na.omit(match(names(df1), df2$Col1))]
```

This will works.

Comment: Sorry, i get an error `Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [74] must be the same length as the vector [5]` with real data

Comment: @ahbon Can you tell me dimension of `df1` role data and `df2` role data of your real data?

Comment: `dim(df1): 69 5; dim(df2): 638  19`, but i use only two columns from `df2`.

Comment: I re-edit `df2`, please check.

Comment: @ahbon New `df2` still works with my answer. I'm trying to reproduce your error.

Comment: Yes, i retested, same error with real data, however it works with @www's solution.

Comment: @ahbon I reproduced your problem and find a solution for it. I add the code above. Please check it out.

Comment: It works right now, many thanks for your help.